# spaces in char array in c

Tags: c, arrays, string, char

how add space between two words in array ,i receive two words from the user his first name ,his last name what i need it to store the two arrays in one array between them a space

here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char first_name[15], last_name[15] ,full_name[32];
    int i=0,i2,first_name_length,last_name_length;
    printf("enter your first name\n");
    first_name_length = scanf("%s",first_name);
    printf("enter your last name\n");
    last_name_length = scanf("%s",last_name);
    for(i2 = 0;i2 < first_name_length;i2++){
        full_name[i] = first_name[i2];
        i++;
    }
    full_name[i++]=' ';
    for(i2 = 0;i2 < last_name_length;i2++){
        full_name[i] = last_name[i2];
        i++;
    }
    printf("%s",full_name);
    return 0;
}
```

the output when enter the "name" value in the both scanf :

```
n n
```

and it should be :

```
name name
```

edit:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char first_name[15], last_name[15] ,full_name[32];
    int i=0,i2;
    printf("enter your first name\n");
    scanf("%14s",first_name);
    printf("enter your last name\n");
    scanf("%14s",last_name);
    for(i2 = 0;first_name[i2];i2++){
        full_name[i] = first_name[i2];
        i++;
    }
    full_name[i++]=' ';
    for(i2 = 0;last_name[i2];i2++){
        full_name[i] = last_name[i2];
        i++;
    }
    printf("%s",full_name);
    return 0;
}
```

the output when enter the "tom" value in the first scanf and "fox" value in the second scanf :

```
tom fox↓@
```

and it should be :

```
tom fox
```

Comment: Your `first_name` and `last_name` are 15 char each and `full_name` is 30.  If you add a space between a max length first_name and max length last_name, you're going to be in trouble.

Comment: i edited my question what's now it doesn't work too it output only the first name but the last name not shown

Comment: You're not incrementing `i` after you set the space, you're incrementing it before hand.

Comment: i edited my question but it still output only the first name but the last name not shown

Comment: @tom fox   Not good to update your post in the fashion you did.  Recommend reverting to the previous version and _appending_ new code, data or insights.

Comment: You aren't nul terminating full_name.  Add full_name[i] = 0; right before the printf, outside the for loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The return value from `scanf()` is the number of fields successfully scanned, not the length of some string.

Use:

```
if (1 != scanf("%14s",first_name)) Handle_EOF_orNoInput();
first_name_length = strlen(first_name);`
```

Same for `last_name`

---

[Edit]

Since OP wants to not introduce new functions (like even `strlen()`), use `"%n` to find the length.  `"%n` record the parsing position.

```
if (1 != scanf("%14s%n",first_name, &first_name_length)) Handle_EOF_orNoInput();
```

OR find length the hard way

```
if (1 != scanf("%14s",first_name)) Handle_EOF_orNoInput();
for (first_name_length = 0; first_name[first_name_length]; first_name_length++);
```

[Edit 2]

OP's latest does not terminate the string.

```
full_name[i] = '\0';  // add this
printf("%s",full_name);
```

Comment: sorry i can't use any other functions expect the written in the code

Comment: @tomfox This is a great answer, you can iterate through `first_name` and look for '/0' instead of `strlen`.

Comment: @Dima Maligin Just put that in.

Comment: i updated the code to simple way but the problem is in the unknown chars

Comment: The problem with your update is that you did not terminate the string.  add  `full_name[i] = 0;` before print.

Comment: @chux Just curious if `char name[10];

 char* p_c = &name[5];

 scanf("%s", p_c);` is posible?

Comment: @DimaMaligin Sure, that works.  Just be careful you don't run off the end of name.

Comment: @Dima Maligin.  Yes - nice idea, code could scan the first name into `full_name` and then scan last name into `scanf("%14s", &full_name[strlen(full_name)]);`  or some variation of this to account for the space, etc.

Comment: @jschultz410 That was just a quick throw that seemed to may be useful, thank you for the confirmation.

Comment: @chux That was the thought behind it :)

Comment: @DimaMaligin The problem with your idea is that it is only safe so long as the target array is big enough to accommodate the maximum sized first and last name, plus a space and nul termination.  In this example, that should be the case here anyway, but in more general cases you need to make sure you can restrict how much input scanf reads in so that you don't run off the end of your allocated memory.  You can do that dynamically by building the matching string to give to scanf on the fly but that's getting pretty complicated.

Comment: @jschultz410 How does your claim differ from any other "pure" `c` code? Aka "pure" `c` is never 100% "safe" and you really need to pay attention to what your doing.

Comment: 32 is a bit small.  Suggest maybe something like 1,000 for [Wolfe+585](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolfe+585,_Senior)

Comment: @jschultz410 Its probably faster than using `strlen` after reading to find the length as well , and pretty sure its much faster that a `for` with a counter.

Comment: @chux: Yes, but only because of the way tomfox defined full_name.  If it were char full_name[20]; (which doesn't make much sense in this example but I was speaking more generally), then you need to be careful and you can't statically encode a safe parameter to scanf in a string literal.  That was my more general point.

Comment: @jschultz410 You must realize that the example was crudely coded, you are absolutely right that one must be careful with this approach. But then again one must be careful a whole lot using `c`, I have seen a lot of barely readable complex code ,and specifically this example is not to complex to implement "safely". I guess you should feel the limit where you can sacrifice readability for performance and still understand a month later what is that chunk of code there.

Answer (score 1):

Rewritten without the sprintf function and without pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char first_name[15], last_name[15] ,full_name[32];
    int src, dest;
    printf("enter your first name\n");
    scanf("%s",first_name);
    printf("enter your last name\n");
    scanf("%s",last_name);

    dest = 0;
    src = 0;
    while (first_name[src] != 0) full_name[dest++] = first_name[src++];
    full_name[dest++] = ' ';
    src = 0;
    while (last_name[src] != 0) full_name[dest++] = last_name[src++];
    full_name[dest] = 0
    printf("%s",full_name);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: sorry i can't use any other functions expect the written in the code

Comment: i can't use the * before the variables

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
i++;
full_name[i]=' ';
```

to

```
full_name[i++]=' ';
```

Your for loop conditions are also not quite right:

```
for(i2 = 0;i2 < first_name_length;i2++){
```

Comment: it out put some unknown characters in the end of the name

Comment: it loops until the chars of the array are finished what's the problem here i didn't type first_name_length any where in the code

Comment: Can you update with your code changes and the output you're getting?

Comment: Looks like I should have checked a better source for the return value of `scanf()`.

Comment: i updated the code to simple way but the problem is in the unknown chars

Answer (score 0):

The function scanf() does not return the number of characters read in.  Rather, it returns the number of successful matches it read in (or error).  In your runs, scanf() is returning 1, so you only copy the first character from first and last name to full name.

Also, you need to initialize full_name to all zeroes or nul terminate it after you are done copying the last name.

Furthermore, the way you are reading in the strings is dangerous.  You should restrict how many characters the scanf() can read in, otherwise it will overflow your buffers and trash your memory (or let a hacker in, etc.):

```
if (1 != scanf("%14s", first_name))
  ; // TODO: handle unexpected input, EOF, error, etc.
```

Or even better:

```
#define STR(x) #x
#define SSTR(x) STR(x)
#define STR_FMT(x) "%" SSTR(x) "s"
#define FIRST_NAME_MAX_LEN 14

...

char first_name[FIRST_NAME_MAX_LEN + 1] = { 0 };

...

if (1 != scanf(STR_FMT(FIRST_NAME_MAX_LEN), first_name))
  ;  // TODO: handle unexpected input, EOF, error, etc.
```

Comment: for some reason i can't use define

Comment: @tomfox Umm, ok, then just hardcode the constants even though that's typically bad form.